# MySQL problem using php when trying to update table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my tbl_category. But when I click on the Update button, it does not show any error. But it does not update the value of tbl_category. I am sure it's very simple since I am a beginner i am not getting well what is wrong exactly so please help me.

Here is the script:

catlist.php

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php';?>
<?php include 'inc/sidebar.php';?>
<?php include("../classes/Category.php");?>
<?php
    $cat = new Category();
    if(isset($_GET['delcat'])){
        $id = $_GET['delcat'];
        //$id = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $_GET['delcat']); 
        $delCat = $cat->delCatById($id);
    }
?>
        <div class="grid_10">
            <div class="box round first grid">
                <h2>Category List</h2>
                <div class="block">   
                    <?php
                        if(isset($delCat)){
                            echo $delCat;
                        }
                    ?>     
                    <table class="data display datatable" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Serial No.</th>
                            <th>Category Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $getCat = $cat->getAllCat();
                        if($getCat){
                            $i = 0;
                            while($result = $getCat->fetch_assoc()){
                               $i++; 
                    ?>
                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $result['catName'];?></td>
                            <td><a href="catedit.php?catid=<?php echo $result['catId'];?>">Edit</a> || <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete!')" href="?delcat=<?php echo $result['catId'];?>">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setupLeftMenu();

        $('.datatable').dataTable();
        setSidebarHeight();
    });
</script>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php';?>
```

catedit.php

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php';?>
<?php include 'inc/sidebar.php';?>
<?php include("../classes/Category.php");?>
<?php
    /*if(!isset($_GET['catid']) || $_GET['catid'] == NULL){
        //echo "<script>window.location = 'catlist.php'; </script>";  
    } else{
        $id = $_GET['catid']; 
    }*/
    $id = isset($_GET['catid']) ? $_GET['catid'] : '';
    //$id = $_GET['catid'];
    $cat = new Category();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $catName = $_POST['catName'];        
        $updateCat = $cat->catUpdate($catName,$id);
    }
?>
        <div class="grid_10">
            <div class="box round first grid">
                <h2>Update Category</h2>
               <div class="block copyblock"> 
                <?php
                   echo $id;
                ?>
                <?php
                   if(isset($updateCat)){
                       echo $updateCat;
                   }
                ?>
                <?php
                   $getCat = $cat->getCatById($id);
                    if($getCat){
                        while($result = $getCat->fetch_assoc()){
                ?>
                <form action="catedit.php" method="post">
                    <table class="form">                    
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="catName" value="<?php echo $result['catName'];?>" placeholder="Enter Category Name..." class="medium" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Update" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <?php 
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php';?>
```

Category.php

```
<?php 
    include_once("../lib/Database.php");
    include_once("../helpers/Format.php");
?>
<?php 
class Category {
    private $db;
    private $fm;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
        $this->fm = new Format();
    }

    public function catInsert($catName){
        $catName = $this->fm->validation($catName); 
        $catName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link , $catName);

        if(empty($catName)){
            $msg = "<span class='error'>Category field must not be empty !</span>";
            return $msg;
        } else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category(catName) VALUES('$catName')";
            $catinsert = $this->db->insert($query);
            if($catinsert){
                $msg = "<span class='success'>Category Inserted Successfully</span>";
                return $msg;
            } else {
                $msg = "<span class='error'>Category Not Inserted.</span>";
                return $msg;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getAllCat(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category ORDER BY catId DESC";
        $result = $this->db->select($query);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getCatById($id){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE catId = '$id'";
        $result = $this->db->select($query);
        return $result;
    }

    public function catUpdate($catName,$id){
        $catName = $this->fm->validation($catName); 
        $catName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link , $catName);
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link , $id);

        if(empty($catName)){
            $msg = "<span class='error'>Category field must not be empty !</span>";
            return $msg;
        } else{
            //$query = "UPDATE tbl_category 
                      //SET 
                      //catName = '$catName' 
                      //WHERE catId = '$id'";
            $query = "UPDATE tbl_category SET catName = '$catName' WHERE catId = '$id'";
            $updated_row = $this->db->update($query);
            if($updated_row){
                $msg = "<span class='success'>Category Updated Successfully</span>";
                return $msg;
            } else {
                $msg = "<span class='error'>Category Not Updated.</span>";
                return $msg;
            }
        }
    }

    public function delCatById($id){
        $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_category WHERE catId = '$id'";
        $delData = $this->db->delete($query);
        if($delData){
            $msg = "<span class='success'>Category Deleted Successfully</span>";
            return $msg;
        }
        else {
            $msg = "<span class='error'>Category Not Deleted.</span>";
            return $msg;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I prefer try debug your self. in below of your query, write **echo $query;** and check its true? all variable is set?

Comment: What do `$this->db->update` and `$this->fm->validation` do? Also, what is returned with this execution, `Category Updated Successfully`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your catedit.php form is submitted, PHP is not receiving 'id', which it needs to be able to execute catUpdate method.

You should have additional (hidden) field in your form which would be for $id. Then, you will take that one from POST as well. $_POST['id'];

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $catName = $_POST['catName'];        
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $updateCat = $cat->catUpdate($catName,$id);
}
....
<form action="catedit.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="i" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```